# How to display SubForm using user contol in C# (Windows Form)

Tags: c#

**I am working on a Windows Froms Application in c# and I use the panel on the main page to display other pages and I want to open a new page through user control in the main panel**

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly that you want to show one `User Control` and hide the other So, you can use the `Visible` property and the code must be like so,

```cs
public void showUserControl(UserControl firstUC, UserControl secondUC) {
     firstUC.Visible = firstUC.Visible ? false : true;
     secondUC.Visible = !firstUC.Visible;
}
```

this method accepts two parameters as a `User Control` and checks if the first one was visible so hide it and show the second one and vice versa

Answer (score -1):

Lets say you have a MainForm which has a panel control in it. Lets name the panel as:

- mainPanel

And lets say you also have 2 UserControls that you want to flick between.  Lets name the 2 UserControls as:

- UserControl1
- UserControl2

If you had 2 button on the form that swapped between the 2 user controls the code in the buttons would look like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    mainPanel.Controls.Clear();
    mainPanel.Controls.Add(new UserControl1());
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    mainPanel.Controls.Clear();
    mainPanel.Controls.Add(new UserControl2());
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your participation, you understood me in a different way, I want to display a page in the MainPanel from a User contol located in another SubForm

Comment: In that case, I think you need to better define what you mean when you say "page"? - What is a page? If a page is a Form of Dialog, then they can only display Controls.

Comment: Yes Sorry for that  i mean Form

Comment: In that case, you cant display a From in another Form.  What I would do is take the contents of the Form you want to display elsewhere and convert it to a UserControl.  Then you can display that UserControl in multiple places. You still need to be careful about the data though. Becauee each form will have seperate instance of the UserControl, you need to be able to pass in the same data class to populate the controsl within the UserContriol so both controls display the same data